# What kind of plant/shrub is this?

Tags: identification

[image: Found somewhere in North Carolina]

This plant was found somewhere in North Carolina. Couldn't get any better pictures, because I'm asking this question on behalf of a friend of mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Cytisus or a Genista of some variety - commonly known as Broom. Usually evergreen, spring flowering shrub, doesn't take well to being pruned hard, should only be lightly clipped over immediately after flowering. No idea which one it is, nor of variety, can't see the overall growth habit and obviously, no flowers are present - the seed pods will be from this year's flowering earlier in the year. They may have viable seeds, but this plant does not necessarily come true from seed.